# Simple cURL POST request via Applescript / Shell

Tags: shell, post, curl, applescript, spotify

I want to send a simple cURL POST request to Spotify to exchange my authorization code for a token that I can use in a little app I'm building. I'm writing it in Applescript.

I've previously figured out how to use GET to search, GET's syntax seems pretty straightforward.

On the other hand I'm having trouble getting Spotify to accept the format I'm sending my data in.

Here is their [developer guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).

Their example request is:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM...zE=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=MQCbtKe...44KN -d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fauth https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

According to their Authorization Guide, I should be able to discard the header in above example and include client_id and client_secret as parameters in the POST body.

(However I note that the syntax they use in the example is different to what I've found elsewhere, including the [cURL manual page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)).

Following Spotify's guide gives me:

```
curl -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=<authcodehere> -d redirect_uri=<redirect_uri> -d client_id=<clientid> -d client_secret=<clientsecret> https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

Adding in `-i -v` for debugging..

Output after running this in Terminal is:

```
* Connected to accounts.spotify.com
* Server certificate: *.spotify.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert Global Root CA
 POST /api/token HTTP/1.1
 Host: accounts.spotify.com
 User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
 Accept: */*
 Content-Length: 410
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 410 out of 410 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx
Server: nginx
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 68
Content-Length: 68
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Keep-Alive: timeout=10

< 
* Connection #0 to host accounts.spotify.com left intact
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid redirect URI"}
```

So I've tried variations of the above POST request to little or no avail.

My most successful attempt:

```
curl -i -v -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/api/token" 
--data "
{\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\",\"code\":\"<authcode>\",\"redirect_uri\":\"
<redirecturi>\",\"client_id\":\"<clientid>\",\"client_secret\":\"<clientsecret>\"}"
```

All on one line obviously. The result:

```
* Connected to api.spotify.com
* Server certificate: *.spotify.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert Global Root CA
> POST /api/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.spotify.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 420
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 420 out of 420 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: nginx
Server: nginx
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 74
Content-Length: 74
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=600
Keep-Alive: timeout=600
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="spotify"
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="spotify"
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800
Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type

< 
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
* Connection #0 to host api.spotify.com left intact
```

Not sure what it wants from me at this stage, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i think you'r missing -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM...zE=" part as a header, at least thats what i understand by the error code 401: Unauthorised.

Comment: Okay. Although, from Spotify's documentation, I should be able to exclude the header and include the client id and client secret as parameters in the POST body instead. if I wanted to use the header though, how would I go about 'encoding' the client id and client secret to base 64 (or whatever it is they want me to do?).

Comment: There are a lot of ways to can encode a string to base64. If you're on a Mac, and I suspect this works for any Linux-distribution as well, you can run `echo -n clientid:clientsecret | base64 -` to output the base64 representation of {clientid}:{clientsecret}. Also want to mention that these authorization flows are not Spotify specific but part of the oAuth 2.0 standard.

Comment: Okay, thanks Michael. Can you see any other reason why it might not work? I'll try the header though.